# Homebrew python 2.7 vs OS X python 2.7

Tags: macos, python-2.7, homebrew

this is my first time asking a question here so sorry in advance if I'm doing something wrong. The problem is I installed python 2 using Homebrew to avoid using OS X system python (since it is recommended to do so), but when I type in the terminal - python, it is still using the system python.

which -a python gives:
    /usr/bin/python

writing python gives:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

and doing python2 gives:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jul 18 2017, 09:16:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

I would like to just write python and not python2 to use the Homebrew version.

Also, echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

and /etc/paths

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/etc/paths (END)
```

What should I do to use Homebrew python and not the default system python.
P.D. I installed python 3 with Hombrew too.

Comment: You could set an alias in your `.bash_profile`, in order for the command `python` to execute the Homebrew installed one, but I would recommend using `pyenv` to better organize all your python versions.

Comment: Have you opened a new Terminal session? Your existing session won't have the new PATH unless you start a new session or `source` your profile.

Answer (score 6):

Homebrew [recently](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/14408) changed the way it handles Python 2.x vs 3.x. It no longer shadows macOS’s `python` by default and instead installs Python 2.x as `python2` and Python 3.x as `python3`.

In fact, it *does* install `python` but doesn’t symlink it in `/usr/local/bin`, hence why your shell can’t find it. If you wish to get everything working as before you need to add it to your `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix python)/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

You could also add an alias from `python` to `python2` and from `pip` to `pip2` but it’s a worse solution because you need one alias for each executable.

```
# in your ~/.bash_profile
alias python=python2
alias pip=pip2
```

Then start a new terminal session for the changes to take effect.

See [the official documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html) for more info. This is also outlined in `brew info python`:

```
$ brew info python
python: stable 2.7.13, HEAD
...
==> Caveats
This formula installs a python2 executable to /usr/local/bin.
If you wish to have this formula's python executable in your PATH then add
the following to ~/.bash_profile:
  export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"

Pip and setuptools have been installed. To update them
  pip2 install --upgrade pip setuptools

You can install Python packages with
  pip2 install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, adding this to my ~/.bash_profile did the trick:
    export PATH="$(brew --prefix python)/libexec/bin:$PATH"
    export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"

Comment: `$(brew --prefix python)` and `/usr/local/opt/python` are equivalent if your Homebrew is installed in `/usr/local` (which it is); you can remove the former ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just go download and install new version [any version of Python 2 or 3  for Mac](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

and make sure you in the correct local (home) directory looks like

```
compname:~ yourname$
```