# python and ipython pointing towards different installations after brew update and upgrade

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I am on macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Today I run

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

It upgraded a bunch of packages and installations including python. After the upgrade, while `ipython` points towards the right installation, `python` does not. For example:

when I type:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

so that:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

but:

```
$ which ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
```

so that

```
$ ipython
Python 2.7.13 (default, Aug 17 2017, 16:42:26)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

or:

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

which is also fine.

of course, my `.bash_profile` includes:

```
 # Homebrew
 export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

and:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

After running `brew upgrade` I installed today also the command line tools with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

since it was recommended during the upgrade, but I doubt this has anything to do with the problem (?)

I have tried

```
$ brew link python
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
```

and then `brew unlink python && brew link python`

but the problem remains.

To summarise: how can I make the installation consistent? or How can I get python to point to the correct installation?

**EDIT**:

During the `brew upgrade` it installed both, python2 and python3. To access to these installations you need to specify the version, so:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which python2
/usr/local/bin/python2

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

and note that I did not have python3 before running `brew upgrade`.

Comment: You might want to give [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) a try.

Comment: HI there @BarryLau. Thanks, but the installation I have is pretty clean (I'd say) and until today, in the many Macs I have set up, I did not have any problems. `brew install python` plus `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` at my .bash_profile and job done. I have used virtualenv in other cases, but here it does not solve my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1025010/upgrading-from-python-to-2-7-10-to-2-7-11-on-osx) out. Apparently, brew only offers 2.7.10 for now. Try downloading the [source code](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2713) and compile it yourself.

Comment: when you upgrade it installs the 2.7.13. Check  this: `ls /usr/local/Cellar/python` returns `2.7.13_1` and if you see the `brew link python` command in my question you'll see it points towards 2.7.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be found by calling:

```
brew info python
```

then one can read

```
==> Caveats
This formula installs a python2 executable to /usr/local/bin.
If you wish to have this formula's python executable in your PATH then add
the following to ~/.bash_profile:
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

so simply add:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

to the `~/.bash_profile` file

And this solves the problem.

Comment: See also [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45630392/735926).

Comment: @bfontaine many thanks, actually my question should probably be flagged as duplicated, since I faced the same problem but encountered in a different way. Your answer is also very good. It was only after two hours installing/uninstalling stuff that occurred to me to do `brew info python` and there it was the solution :) thanks again