# Python Which Python provides default path in MacOS

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

First of all I apologize about the unclarity of my previous question.

So When I install Homebrew and execute Which Python it gives,

`usr/bin/python` instead of `usr/local/bin/python`

**What I have Done So far with help of a Stackoverflow user**

When I run the `type python` it gives me, `python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)`

When I execute `print os.environ['PATH']` in python to find the environment path, it gives, `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin‌`

and finally when I run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python`, it gives me,
`/usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory`

Also I used `brew doctor` command and it shows `Your system is ready to brew` and also did unlink and link python using `brew link python`

But whenever I run `which python3` it shows the path I want. Seems like it does not include the file `python` in `/usr/local/bin`

Still had no luck of changing it to `/usr/local/bin` to install OpenCV. Please help me.

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is it that you are wanting? Are you wanting calls to python to execute /usr/local/bin/python instead of /usr/bin/python? When you say which python3 shows the path you want, what does that mean? What is the path it shows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Mac OS use the python installed by Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419500/how-to-make-mac-os-use-the-python-installed-by-homebrew)

Comment: @DavidJenkins The problem is when I try to install opencv it denies to upgrade pip and other packages because system python has restricted by Apple. So the online tutorial says that I have to make sure `which python` should show the brew path.

Comment: Why not use python3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homebrew python 2.7 vs OS X python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622838/homebrew-python-2-7-vs-os-x-python-2-7)

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45630392/735926